# Place to meet gamers for co-op

Tags: pc

I am looking for a place to meet similar minded gamers to play co-op with. I know Goozex has the playing now tab, but it is severely under utilized. ([Left 4 Dead example](http://www.goozex.com/trading/asp/itemdetail.asp?item=45927&tab=P#tabsection)). Xbox Live has the recent played with list, but I am looking for something more PC based.

Pretty much I just got Borderlands and looking for ways to play with people, but I want to expand the question for generality.

I would prefer finding people to consistently play with, but for sake of generality, answers can be for both consistent and random people.

Note: I am trying to avoid making this question too specific and subject to closing. Comments or edits to properly modify the question is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to play with random people or a group of people you can consistently play with?

Comment: This is a tricky kind of question to handle. Too specific, and the answers may be too localized to the answerer to be able to help you. Too open-ended, and the answers will end up too vague and unusable for what you need it for. This, I honestly find, is something better addressed in a back-and-forth than trying to get an authoritative answer. There are too many factors to consider, regarding what channels are available for that game and how easy it is to arrange things, to make a strong general answer viable.

Comment: @Grace: If such a service existed (to match up co-op gamers specifically), I don't think it would be open-ended or have vague answers at all.  However, I personally don't know of any such service.

Comment: @BlueRaja The fact no single service exists to cater to all co-op games is rather my point.

Comment: @Grace, @BlueRaja...I agree with both of you, although if no service exists I believe that is an appropriate answer. If multiple services did exist, answers would report service and users would vote on the quality of the services. Unfortunately there is a lack of services to vote on, which can be an answer in on itself

One Solution is turning this into a community wiki that lists services or sites based on criteria, avoiding an end all strong answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually go about this a few ways.

- Play online and meet people.  Joining pubs is a good way to meet good gamers to play with
- Visit the official forums of the game and see who is looking
- Use something like Steam or XFire to find groups of people who like the game.  This can be community groups or sub-forums.
- If I find a server run by a group/clan and I am enjoying myself on it then I will usually check out their site.  Sometimes it leads to joining, other times it just leads to more friends to play with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Those are all good options. If you're feeling extra ambitious you can also try and join a clan. This way you not only have some set people to befriend and play with, but they'll probably be good at the game and have plenty of tips and tricks to teach you.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about clans. Updating original post with another thing I forgot pertaining to them.

Answer (score 3):

[Gameranger](http://www.gameranger.com/about/) is an excellent application which allows you to create and join either public or private rooms for over 600 different games, including Borderlands. It comes with a built-in friends list and messenger to help you arrange games with your friends. You don't even need to have the game running when you start the game in the room; Gameranger will automatically open the game you chose and set up the game as though you were using LAN for almost-immediate play. It definitely helps to take away the hassle involved in multiplayer and meet new people playing the same co-op games you are.